# Using edging where people walk across

Tags: patio, masonry, landscaping, driveway, gravel

I'm building a gravel patio inside my U-shaped gravel driveway. I will be using two different kinds of gravel, so I need a separator at the border to prevent the mixing of the two types of gravel. If I use some kind of edging, wouldn't it become a trip hazard if it sticks above the surface? And if it's below the surface, wouldn't it be ineffective at preventing mixing? Any way out of this conundrum?

Comment: So you're doomed if it above the surface and doomed if it's below the surface.... so install the edging at the finished grade of the gravel, right even with it.

Comment: Concrete,,, exposed aggregate gives the look of gravel and won’t move.